# wearing sunglasses on shabbas

Tags: halacha, shabbat, clothing, see-sight-vision-blind, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

Can one wear non-prescription sunglasses on shabbas in a place where there is no eruv? Do we say since if the sun gets blocked one might come to take them off in a karm'lis, or do we say it's like regular glasses?

Answer (score 5):

R. Neuwirth in Shemirat Shabbat Kehilchata (16:24) writes that one should not wear ordinary sunglasses in a place where there is no Eruv because they are not considered clothing. However, if the sunglasses are never taken off even indoors (eg. for medical reasons) then they are considered clothing and can be worn even outdoors with no Eruv. In footnote 94 he writes that if the ordinary sunglasses (which would be taken off indoors) are needed for medicinal purposes, there is potentially room for leniency to wear them outdoors with no Eruv if the area is not a Reshut Harabbim Deoraita and the wearer is careful not to take them off even in the shade while outdoors.

Answer (score -2):

don't think it matters either way. glasses are part of your clothing. you don't need an eruv for clothing, only things you are actually carrying. another example... using a shabbos shabbos key belt. no longer carrying because the belt is now part of your clothing

Comment: There are certain types of clothing which cannot be worn outside an Eruv.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: A signet ring or shoes with nails in them.

Comment: so the rambam makes a statement about a ring which is unfit normally for a man to wear would be unfit for him to wear on shabbos b/c the normal way for him to transfer such an item would not be by wearing it. Are you trying to say that a signet ring is not a ring appropriate for a man to wear and what is that based on?

Comment: You should check out Chapter 6 of tractate _Shabbat_.