# Clip on flip shades on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat

Can one wear these type of clip on flip shades on Shabbos in an area with no Eruv?[image: Clip on flip shades]

(They clip on to your regular prescription glasses.)

As noted in this Mi Yodeya answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/41026/wearing-sunglasses-on-shabbas):

> R. Neuwirth in Shemirat Shabbat Kehilchata (16:24) writes that one should not wear ordinary sunglasses in a place where there is no Eruv because they are not considered clothing. However, if the sunglasses are never taken off even indoors (eg. for medical reasons) then they are considered clothing and can be worn even outdoors with no Eruv.

My question here is for the many people I see who do in fact wear regular sunglasses. Are these flip up attachments any worse? Is there more of a Shema Yishlof (fear they will be removed in a Reshus Harabim) concerning them?

Comment: How is it different from a hood on your coat that zips on and off?

Comment: This is not a beged. Also they are arguably silly looking and shema yishlof may apply.

Comment: How is this less of a beged than [sun]glasses in general? Do we really worry about shma yishlof nowadays (OC 303:18)?

Comment: Do we need to re evaluate traditional answers to this question in light of the growing medical consensus that consistently wearing sunglasses is an important factor in long term eye health? (I am not the world's best example but I wear sunglasses outdoors much more often than I would otherwise, because my eye doctor told me to always wear sunglasses to help avoid cataracts.)

Answer (score 3):

While double checking the source in the linked answer, I realized that Shemiras Shabbos Kehilchasa actually address this exact item.

In chapter 18 siff 18 subsection 2 (in my edition) he says it is allowed:

> משקפי שמש המחוברים על ידי ציר למשקפיים רגילים, והמרכיב אותם אינו מסירם מן המשקפיים גם במקום צל אלא רק מגביהם- מותר לצאת בהם לרשות הרבים

Comment: In any case, you should always CYLOR for practical halachic advice.